# What are the ground motion prediction equations for 3-D ruptures?

Tags: geophysics, seismology, earthquakes

[Ground motion prediction equations](http://web.stanford.edu/~bakerjw/GMPEs.html) (GMPEs) estimate ground motion at any given site due to an earthquake at a distance. There are many such equations, each with different parameters.

Can somebody please suggest those equations which can estimate peak ground acceleration (PGA) values from a 3-D rupture from parameters like rupture distance, Joyner–Boore distance, and so on?

Comment: First principles from Green's Equations?

Comment: The elasto-dynamic wave equation (basically the momentum equation) is all you need to predict ground motion locally (0-100s of km) due to slip on faults.

Comment: @stali that sounds like the beginning of a good answer to this question.

Comment: @SabreTooth The details aren't very useful. If OP wants he can read a pre-print of mine at http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0429v2.pdf

Comment: Check at the compilation on http://www.gmpe.org.uk. After a quick look I didn't find any, but maybe you can give it a harder look.